# Dynamic Quorum set configuration for master node - Add / Remove Validators

Tags: stellar-core

Is it possible to dynamically set / configure validators in  a Quorum set?

For example I have a Quorum set of 4 nodes say - {A,B,C,D}. Which have equal slice or equal participation.

Now, if we would like to add a new node say "E" :

1) Do I need to update all config files on A,B,C and D nodes manually to include new node as a validator ?

2) How this process can be automated or simplified ?

Any information will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes, the quorumset is solely configured via the config file. You have to update the config file and restart stellar-core afterwards.

2) Manage your config files in a (i.e. git) repository and use some deployment tool. Simplest approach would be a simple shellscript that pulls changes, rsyncs config to each node and restarts it via ssh.